# Kubernetes Volume Mount Permissions Incorrect For Secret

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I am mounting a k8s secret as a volume mount, and the files in the pod have the wrong permissions.

In my `Deployment` I have this entry in the `volumes` array:

```
        - name: ssh-host-keys
          secret:
            secretName: ftp-ssh-host-keys
            defaultMode: 0600
```

which is then mounted like this:

```
            - mountPath: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
              name: ssh-host-keys
              subPath: ssh_host_rsa_key
              readOnly: true
```

However, when I look at the files in the `Pod` the file permissions are incorrect:

```
rw-r--r-- 1 root root 553122 Aug 21  2018 moduli
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1723 Aug 21  2018 ssh_config
-rw-r----- 1 root 1337    410 May 11 10:33 ssh_host_ed25519_key
-rw-r----- 1 root 1337   3242 May 11 10:33 ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 1337    465 May 11 10:33 sshd_config
```

i.e. the keys have permissions 0644 instead of 0600.

I don't know why this might be happening.

Comment: Can you please share your full manifest so I can test it on my lab?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 14):

According to the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#secret-files-permissions), owing to JSON limitations, you must specify the mode in decimal notation.

Look to the example provided in the documentation:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mypod
    image: redis
    volumeMounts:
    - name: foo
      mountPath: "/etc/foo"
  volumes:
  - name: foo
    secret:
      secretName: mysecret
      defaultMode: 256
```

256 decimal is equivalent to 0400 in octal. In your specific case, you should use `defaultMode: 384` to get 0600 to have the desired permissions.

You can convert octal permissions [here](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/octal-to-decimal.html).

Comment: thanks, but that's not the issue. The deployment shows the correct values even when I when I fetch it using ```kubectl get deployment ... -o yaml```

Comment: Please, share the output of `kubectl get deployment ... -o yaml`.

Comment: That's JSON limitation. Not YAML!

Answer (score 6):

I think a common confusion is that the files are linked, so `ls` will show the link permissions by default. See more details [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/34982).

Simply add -L: `ls -laL /path/to/directory/` to dereference the link

If that doesn't do the trick, maybe you are facing [this bug](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/57923).

Comment: Files are not always linked, it depends on how secrets are being mounted. As you can see on his `ls -l` output, he doesn't have links.

Comment: This is not the case here as said by the comment above